# Why is my CPU slowing down? (power settings and temperature are OK)

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-speed

I realise others have posted similar questions, but I'm having trouble working out why my processor isn't running at full speed. I'll keep this visual.

**Given this:**

[image]

**...and this:**

[image]

**... why does CPU-Z flip between this:**

[image]

**...and this:**
*(compare clock speed and multiplier with last image)*

[image]

**...and LatencyMon says this?**

```
Reported CPU speed:                 2799.0 MHz
Measured CPU speed:                 2283.0 MHz (approx.)
```

**...and RealTemp says this:**
*(so it's not being throttled due to overheating)*

[image]

I'm at a loss here. **Why is it being throttled when the CPU is not under a significant load or overheating?**

- **BIOS** - Phoenix AwardBios 6.00
- **Motherboard** - Foxconn G31MX

Comment: If you want to check your CPU's performance under load, try software like prime95. This will cause severe stress on your CPU so don't do it if you have any cooling problems or your CPU will be throttled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the processor lowering its multiplier to save power while it's idling.

The Intel E7400 CPU comes with [Idle States](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-031505.htm#8) technology. When the processor sees that it has no load or a small load, it will decrease it clock multiplier. This effectively lowers the speed of the CPU to help save power. If the CPU see's that is has a big load, it will automatically increase back to the rated speed of the processor.

You can see this in your CPU-Z pictures. The multiplier box has a range from `x6 - x10.5` (in 0.5 increments) making your speed anywhere from 1.60 GHz to 2.80 GHz.

Somethimes, even when you set the Minimum Processor State to 100%, settings in the BIOS/CPU type may ignore that request. There might be a Quiet 'n Cool setting in the BIOS (or something related to power saving) that would override the Windows setting.

Comment: Thanks, as long as the CPU is hitting top speed when I need it to that's fine. It seems the `LatencyMon` figure is just a guess averaged from the two possible clock speeds. I did a few CPU-intensive things with `RealTemp` on and it did show the speed going up to 2.80GHz so seems all is well.